# Passing createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, url, audio, fileapi

I want to pass the address created by `window.URL.createObjectURL(file)` to dancer.js but I get `GET blob:http%3A//localhost/b847c5cd-aaa7-4ce0-8ff8-c13c6fc3505a.mp3 404 (Not Found)`.

I manage to create an audio element with a file selected through a file input, but dancer.js simply does not find the file... any ideas? (Below how i pass the ObjectURL)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
        $('body').append('<audio id="audio" controls="controls"></audio>');
        $('#audio').append('<source src='+window.URL.createObjectURL(file)+' type=audio/mpeg />')
        $('body').append('<a href='+window.URL.createObjectURL(file)+'>link</a>')
        dancer(window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
    })
})
```

Comment: You should use `createObjectURL` once and store the address in a variable instead of calling it every time you use it. Creating a new object URL for the same file every time you use it is [creating a lot of unnecessary overhead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.URL.createObjectURL).

Comment: thx, but it did not help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [dancer.js readme](https://github.com/jsantell/dancer.js/blob/master/README.md) it looks like the `load` method will take either a reference to a `<audio>` element or a configuration object that specifies the source: `{scr: varHoldingFileURL}`. Since you are already creating a `<audio>` element for your file I'd just pass that to dancer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dancer = new Dancer(),
        fileURL;

    $("#submit").click(function(){
            var audioElement,
                file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];

            fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);

            // remove any preexisting instances of the audio tag
            $('#audio').remove();

            // Revoke any previously used file URL so it doesn't
            // take up memory anymore.
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);

            $('body').append('<audio id="audio" controls="controls"></audio>');
            $('#audio').append('<source src='+ fileURL +' type=audio/mpeg />')
            $('body').append('<a href=' + fileURL +'>link</a>')

            // get a reference to the audio element we created
            audioElement = $('#audio')[0];

            dancer.load(audioElement);
    })
});
```